# Which background color will be appealing for white text?

Tags: visual-design

For my UX portfolio, I was planning to display the title in white. I was looking for some suggestions for the color scheme I could use and a decent background for the white title text. Thank you.

Comment: This seems more of a graphic design issue as opposed to a UX issue

Comment: This is not the part of user experience instead it is the part of design.

Comment: Some useful answers on this subject: http://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=white+text+on

Comment: @RicardoTomasi thank you this really help, this is what i've been seeking.

Answer (score 3):

Dark backgrounds can be particularly good for white text But there are some guidelines to follow when doing so:

> When reversing colour out, eg white text on black, make sure you
>   increase the leading, tracking and decrease your font-weight. This
>   applies to all widths of Measure. White text on a black background is
>   a higher contrast to the opposite, so the letterforms need to be wider
>   apart, lighter in weight and have more space between the lines.

Refer these articles - [Five simple steps to better typography](http://markboulton.co.uk/journal/five-simple-steps-to-better-typography)
and [Dos and Don’ts of Dark Web Design](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2009/08/the-dos-and-donts-of-dark-web-design/)

Also, you can explore color scheme from here - https://color.adobe.com/explore/newest/